# Get the y position of a view inside of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm currently working on a `UITextField` which makes will expose a `UITableView` when a list of results is filled based on the input in the `UITextField`. So it's basically an `autocomplete` functionality.

Everything works and draws just fine when you use it in a normal UIView however as soon as I put my `UITextField` in a structure like this

> |- UIView
>      |-- UIScrollView
>      |--- UIView
>      |---- UIView
>      |----- UIImageView
>      |----- UITextField

The table gets drawn in the wrong position. This is what I do to calculate the frame of the TableView:

```
exposedFrame = CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: self.frame.maxY, width: view.frame.width, height: tableHeight)
```

where `view` is the top `UIView` and `self` is the `UITextField`.

So in this instance the Y position is incorrect.
However the question is how will I be able to obtain the correct y position inside of the scrollview?

Answer (score -1):

The calculation seems to be correct. I think you're adding the table view to the wrong view (maybe the scroll view, assuming from the question title).

> |- UIView
>
> |-- UIScrollView
>
> |--- UIView
>
> |---- UIView --> **Add table view here!**
>
> |----- UIImageView
>
> |----- UITextField

*My experience:* I'm not sure if you'll need this, but I recently had to implement a similar pop-over control. Whenever I had to add this subview, I also had to call the superView's layoutIfNeeded. I did this using delegation. Also, note that the superView's layoutSubViews should have a logic to recalculate its height after the table is added. Else, the table appears but is not interactable (at least in my case)